# How to create package spec and body dynamically using execute immediate? 

Tags: oracle10g, package, dynamic-sql

I have a package which contains more than 2000 lines. My question is can I create the packages dynamically by using `execute immediate`?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the associative array `DBMS_SQL` interface assuming that "2000 lines" equates to more than 32k worth of text.  That means that you'll need to load the DDL into multiple elements of an associative array before passing that to the `DBMS_SQL.PARSE` method.  Something like this works

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2    l_sql dbms_sql.varchar2a;
  3    c     integer;
  4  begin
  5    l_sql(1) := 'CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_dynamic ';
  6    l_sql(2) := 'AS ';
  7    l_sql(3) := '  PROCEDURE my_proc;';
  8    l_sql(4) := 'END;';
  9    c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
 10    dbms_sql.parse( c, l_sql, 1, 4, true, dbms_sql.native );
 11* end;
SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> desc pkg_dynamic;
PROCEDURE MY_PROC
```

But I would strongly question why you are trying to use dynamic SQL to create packages in the first place.  It doesn't generally make sense to write code that turns around and generates more code.  You wouldn't, for example, generally want to write a Java application that turned around and wrote and compiled another Java application that someone would then run.